# Image assets not working for size classes in universal application

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageasset

I am trying to give different image for my universal app, that is for iPhone`(compact,any[-,*])` and iPad `(regular,regular[+,+])`. When I run the app for iPhone, it is always taking image I placed in [*,*], below is my settings in my image assets.

So for me if I use below settings for iPhone I am not getting image, even though i added image in `(compact,any[-,*])`

[image]

P.S. If i select iPhone and iPad instead of universal in image assets it is working, But it is not working in iPad split screen multitasking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be apple bug, for image view it is working correctly, but for UIButton it is having issues.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16116